# Maurer Cartan form and Levi-Civita Connection

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras

I know that through the Maurer Cartan form on Lie Groups it's possible to define a Cartan connection. Let us suppose to restrict ourself to Matrix groups.

Is the Cartan connection originated by the Maurer Cartan form the same as the Levi-Civita connection? If not when they do coincide?

Comment: What do you mean by *the* Levi-Civita connection?

Comment: And what do you mean by a Cartan connection? You might be interested in [this MathOverflow post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/86782/metric-connections-on-a-lie-group).

Comment: For Cartan connection I simply mean a connection defined by 1-forms, as results through the Maurer-Cartan form